# Handling multiple values in DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a query that gets all the distinct values from a column, and if there are multiple values, it should select the highest one.

like if I have a table schema like:

> **EmployeeName | Task | TimeGiven**

and employee can have multiple entry for a same `Task`, and I want to get all the distinct `Tasks` for all employees with the highest `TimeGiven` for them, how can I do that?

Edit
DataSet:

```
EmployeName Task        TimeGiven
Mr. X       R&D         30
Mr. X       R&D         50
Mr. X       Devlpmnt    31
Mr. X       Devlpmnt    60
Mr. Y       R&D         40
Mr. Y       R&D         10
Mr. Y       R&D         90
Mr. Y       Devlpmnt    10

**Result Needed:**
Mr. X       R&D         50
Mr. X       Devlpmnt    60
Mr. Y       R&D         90
Mr. Y       Devlpmnt    10
```

what I need is for every Employee, get the highest `TimeGiven` for each task!

Comment: Have you tried to handle this task either with temporary table or with views?

Comment: I am using views, but not sure how they will help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use `group by`:

```
select EmployeeName
  , Task
  , TimeGiven = max(TimeGiven)
from t1
group by EmployeeName
  , Task
```

**Edit after comment:**

Do you mean something like:

```
select Task
  , TimeGiven = max(TimeGiven)
from t1
group by Task
```

All I've done is remove the employee from the query - this will give all tasks with the highest recorded TimeGiven for each task regardless of which employee performed the task.

I'm still not clear if that's what you need... If not, please give an example dataset and your desired output.

**Edit after dataset added:**

The first query gives the correct results. All I did was add an order by clause to give your exact resultset:

```
select EmployeeName
  , Task
  , TimeGiven = max(TimeGiven)
from tasks
group by EmployeeName
  , Task
order by EmployeeName
  , Task desc
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/260e4/3). Click here to see it in action.

Comment: actually I want to get maximum `TimeGiven` for every emplyee. Sorry for not clearing that in question!

Comment: See above; the original answer works as required; I've added a demo showing this in action.